# Solr query with words containing letters and numbers

Tags: solr, solrnet

My client has several keywords that are commonly searched for that contain a letter and numbers:

```
M4
M12
M18
M28
```

When these get searched in Solr right now, they are getting tokenized as both the full string and as the letter `M` along with the number, so if someone searches for `M12`, the search is performed on `M`, `12`, and `M12`.

What is the best way to prevent this so it only searches for `M12`?

**EDIT:** Figured I should include the tokenizer/filter configuration for the field's type, so here it is:

```
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1" />
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
<filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />
```

Comment: I think you just need to take out the word delimiter filter. Maybe define your field with the built-in `type="string"` instead of whatever this custom type is called.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the solution was pretty easy. Alex's comment helped me get there, but I ended up just modifying the word delimiter filter, settings `splitOnNumerics=0`:

```
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1" splitOnNumerics="0" />
```